# What do the arguments inside an ajax function refer to?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I often see this in ajax function `function(event, data, status, xhr)`. I'm wondering what those arguments refer to and how they are used.

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to each event or function, it's usually relatively well explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `data`: The data returned by the server (could be HTML, XML, JSON, ...)
- `status`: a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror")
- `xhr`: the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) used to send the AJAX request

In 99.99% of the cases all you care about is the `data` returned by the server. You might also be interested whether the ajax request succeeded or failed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somescript.cgi',
    success: function(data) {
        // The request succeeded => do something with the data returned by the server
    },
    error: function() {
        // The request failed
    }
});
```